# Kryonet doesn't send one specific packet

Tags: java, tcp, kryonet

I have a Java network application realized with kryonet.
The problem is that every packet is sent correctly but specific class doesn't reach the server.
I have registered all the classes, here a brief overview:

```
... 
kryo.register(User.class, 1242);
kryo.register(ProjectMetaData.class, 1343);
kryo.register(ProjectMetaVectorResponse.class,1244);
...
```

It doens't transmit ProjectMetaData but all other classes (yes, the ids are correct.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the error: we have had different class dependencies on server and client. Strange is though, that there weren't any errors...